# Bootstrap: Toggler not displaying its content

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am building a basic website with React, using also Reactstrap (bootstrap 4 documentation).
I have a basic Navbar with some items and a toggler button when the width of the viewport is small.
Problem is when clicked on the toggler it does not display anything. Why?
When the screen returns in large width, though, the dropdown menu of the services tab it appears open so it seems that the toggler somehow it is only linked to it and not to the whole navbar. Ideas?

Navbar:

```
export default class MainNavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.scrolNav = this.scrolNav.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      class_up: 'whentop',
      class_down: 'nav_top',
      dropdownOpen: false
    };
  }

// prova scroll adaptive navbar

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrolNav);
}


componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrolNav)
}


scrolNav() {
    const scrolly = window.scrollY;
    if (scrolly > 80) {
        this.setState({
          class_up: 'whenscroll',
          class_down: 'nav_down'
        })
    }   
    else if (scrolly < 80) {
        this.setState({
          class_up: 'whentop',
          class_down: 'nav_top'
        });

    }
}


  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div  className={this.state.class_up}>
        <Navbar className={this.state.class_down} color="light" light expand="md">
        <a href="/"><img className="logonowrite" src={logoNoWrite} width="80px" alt=""/>
          <NavbarBrand id="write_logo"><img src={write} className="write_logo" alt=""/></NavbarBrand></a>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />   
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <Dropdown nav isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
            <DropdownToggle nav caret>
              Services
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownItem><Link to="/rec_services">Recruitment Solutions</Link></DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem><Link to="/web_services">Web Design</Link></DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem><Link to="/mark_services">SEO & Digital Marketing</Link></DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </Dropdown>                
              <NavItem>
              <Link className="int_link" to="/">Home</Link>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <Link className="int_link_about" to="about">About</Link>
              </NavItem>
               <NavItem>
                <Link className="int_link_about" to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>    
               </NavItem> 
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Collapse Component  `<Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>` is searching for the state isOpen. When you click the `toggler` you set state of `dropdownOpen` and not `isOpen` that Collpase is searching for.

So prolly you need to change to `<Collapse isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} navbar>`

P.S not tested

Comment: Yeah it actually worked :). I also had to split the toggle() method, one for the services dropdown and one of the general toggle button itself to avoid to close / open both of them at the same time. Do you know other methods/frameworks on how to build a better Navbar? With Bootstrap it looks very outdated, boring and it is hard to customize....

Comment: For navabar especially I don't have something specific, but I use the ant.design lately and it is pretty sweet. Check it out